# Display data from join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page where it displays a movie review, that is displayed by a link `<a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] .  '"> Read Review </a>` on this same page I would also like to display the movie title. So do I have to use a join to display the information or is there a simpler way of doing it ? I have tried using a few queries but I end up getting all the film titles for the one review.

This is where the query first starts on the film.php

```
$query = "SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review,
      users.username
      FROM films
      LEFT JOIN reviewed ON films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id
      LEFT JOIN users ON films.user_id=users.user_id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute mysql" . mysql_error());

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num > 0) { // If it ran ok, display records.

echo "<p> There are curently $num records.</p>";

// Table header.
 echo '<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Movie Title</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>Leading Actor</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>Rating</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>Author</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>Review</b></td>
</tr>';

// Fetch and print all the records.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td align="left">' . $row['movie_title'] . '</td>
    <td align="left">' . $row['actor'] . '</td>
    <td align="left">' . $row['rating'] . '</td>
    <td align="left">' . $row['username'] . '</td>
    <td align="left"><a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] .  '"> Read Review </a>
    </tr> ';
}
}
?>
```

Now on this page is displays the review but I would like to display the movie_title within the sub_review container.

```
<body>

    <div id="sub_review_container">

        <?php




        ?>

    </div>

    <div id="Review_container">

    <?php

    $review = $_GET['id'];

    echo $review;

    ?>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Give an alias to films table and user table like `films a` and `users b`

Comment: Insert obligatory "For the love of God, *stop using `mysql_query()`*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the id of the review in the query of which you want to show the review.

Also because of left join. It is showing all records. You should use inner join for reviews and films. It should be like:

```
 $query = "SELECT films.movie_title as movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review, users.username FROM films INNER JOIN reviewed ON films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id INNER JOIN users ON films.user_id=users.user_id where reviewed.id = ... "
```

...`reviewed.id` will be the Id you pass from page.

Comment: Please indent code with four spaces or use the `{}` button to format it for you. It's not very readable otherwise.

Comment: Done. Actually wasn't getting any option on phone.